# SharePoint 2013 - This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm

Tags: error, farm, server

This error appears frequently and sometime disappears after refresh

> This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from the configuration database. To connect this server to the server farm, use the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, located on the Start menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products.

[image: This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from the configuration database. To connect this server to the server farm, use the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, located on the Start menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products.]

Comment: try accessing your database with the credentials you are using for login in your sharepoint site.

Comment: If you are unable to login with the credentials you have for the DB then check my answer. It will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue would occur if the user account  "UserAccountName" or "Administrator" doesn’t have enough permission in the SQL server contents databases of SharePoint site collections in your machine. So, add the "UserAccountName" to your MSSQL server by following the below steps:

1. Go to that server and open the SQL SharePoint instant using Management Studio.
2. Then in the "Object Explorer" you can see the "Security" tree menu at the bottom. Expand that menu and Go to "Log in" and right click it and click "New Login". Then put your login there and under server roles select "sysadmin".

You can refer [This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/this-operation-can-be-performed-only-on-a-computer-that-is-joined-to-a-server-farm-by-users-who-have-permissions-in-sql-server-to-read-from-the-configuration-database/) link.

Answer (score 15):

I got the same error and i did the following steps and worked for me.

Go To **services.msc** 
Restart the **SQL Server (SharePoint) & SQL Server Agent (SHAREPOINT)**
Check the web site, It'll work.

[image]

Hope this will help to any one.

Comment: Great!! that helped me a lot.

Comment: In my case, Sql server agent service (SHAREPOINT) was disabled.

Comment: In my case `SQL Server Agent (SHAREPOINT)` was disabled. I restarted only the `SQL Server (SHAREPOINT)` service and it worked for me.

Comment: In my case `SQL Server (SHAREPOINT)` service wasn't started.

Comment: is this something that's actually on the sql server?

Comment: I don't seem to actually have those services on any of the machines on my farm.

Comment: Yes, @Matt Please check on your server where the SQL is installed.

Comment: we got it squared away it was related to SCOM but thanks for responding

Answer (score 2):

In my case the user account under which apppool for web application was running was locked. unlocking the user account solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

- User was already in **sysAdmin** group in SQL Server
- **Restarting SQL services** did not work
- Account was **not locked**..

  **IIS Reset did work :)**

Answer (score 0):

The scenario I faced was as follow:

- A power failure caused all server in the company get down
- After restarting the power all servers started again
- In some cases and for some misterious reasons the sql server service was not configured to run automatically (I have no access to the database center) and so the SharePoint SQL Server Service did not start
- The Solution was to restart the SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was that the "Security/Logins" of a new Instance clustered in a AlwaysOn High Availability Group, has replicated all the environment and application DDBB but not the logins.

I've created manually all the missing logins on to the new SQL AlwaysOn AG, copying them from the Master and worked properly.

Hope this information could help in the future, User Logins doesn't replicate on a AlwaysOn AG.