# Server Error in '/' Application when contacting SQL server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

We have migrated Sharepoint 2013 application VM and Sharepoint SQL VM to new fresh server. Now when accessing it we get an application error:
[image]

It seems like the app VM cannot access SQL VM. But logins are working, I can assess DB via SQL server management studio with domain user. It is like config DB cannot be accessed.
Any ideas? How to troubleshoot?

EDIT:
When accessing Central Admin the error is:

[image]

EDIT:
Troubleshooting Allen_MSFT first link:

No | The Database Server is down.

No | The SQL Server Services are stopped.

No | The Database server is not reachable from the Application server (Firewall Issue / SQL Server Port is closed).

No | The SQL Server license has expired.

?  | The SQL Server Service account credentials were changed.
(MSSQLSERVER service is made Logon as Local System Account)

No | The App Pool account for web application is locked or disabled.

No | The farm account is locked or disabled.

No | The farm account password is expired.

?  | The farm account doesn’t have
Allow Logon locally.
Logon as Service.
(On which service?)

?  | The farm account doesn’t have sufficient permission on the database server, configuration database, and content databases.
(The farm admin did not existed in SQL DB server security logins. After creating it the error appears (see pic below))

No | The SharePoint Configuration database is in recovery mode and its status is not online.

?  | The farm servers are not joined properly.
(I cannot join them, got error)

[image]

[image]

Comment: any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a reference to the following articles and similar threads:

- [This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from the configuration database](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/this-operation-can-be-performed-only-on-a-computer-that-is-joined-to-a-server-farm-by-users-who-have-permissions-in-sql-server-to-read-from-the-configuration-database/)
- [SharePoint 2013 - This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119306/sharepoint-2013-this-operation-can-be-performed-only-on-a-computer-that-is-joi)
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/ea54e26c-1728-48d4-b2c5-2a3376a1082c/this-operation-can-be-performed-only-on-a-computer-that-is-joined-to-a-server-farm-by-users-who-have?forum=sharepointgeneral